# Is it possible to assign data attributes using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, custom-data-attribute

Could I add data attributes to an element via it's CSS?

```
.myClass{
/* assign data attribute here */
}
```

Comment: `data` attributes aren't CSS...

Comment: You could easily achieve selector/data pairs with a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS is for presentation not data(manipulating markup).

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.  You'd have to use something else, like javascript.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not what CSS should be used for.
The idea of CSS is precisely to be all about the presentation and not at all about the data.
What you may do, if you have to, is to have different possible values in different elements, and change by CSS which element is visible.